# Как вынуть тег video с помощью Jsoup если сайт создает его через javascript

Tags: java, android, парсер, jsoup

Есть видео хостинг где нужно пропарсить сайт и вынуть оттуда ссылку на видео и вставить её в videoview на андроид устройстве вот сам сайт http://mix.tj/video/113989.html при просмотре кода страницы можно найти вот этои строки

```
<script>var player = jwplayer('player-embed');      
player.setup({"file": "http://dushanbe.mix.tj/video/2/45/5bafae1306081.mp4", "image": "/img/b/7/42/113989.jpg", "aspectratio": "16:9", "autostart": false, "controls": true, "displaydescription": false, "displaytitle": false, "flashplayer": "/player/jwplayer-7.8.7/jwplayer.flash.swf", "key": "n+94L7vjfQNGEin57ap3glk3iRNum2o7AeOIWw==", "mute": false, "ph": 1, "pid": "mS6Np6yN", "preload": "auto", "primary": "html5",  "repeat": false, "stagevideo": false, "stretching": "uniform", "width": "100%"});</script>
```

Но при парсинге ни тега `<video>` ни тега `<script>` не видно вот пример парсинга на Java

```
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                document = Jsoup.connect("http://mix.tj/video/113989.html").get();


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(document != null)
            {

                Log.e("Title",document.title());
                Elements e =  document.getElementsByTag("script");
                int i = 0;
                for(Element element : e){

                    if(element.text().charAt(0) == 'v')
                    {
                        Log.e(String.valueOf(i),element.text());
                    }
                    i++;
                }

            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Открывал сайт через Хром,плеер "спрятан" в div ,а не в script.  div class="fp-player" Проверьте сайт.

Comment: да но если открыть исходник сразу-же после открытия файла там видно что этот плеер создается через JavaScript поэтому во время парсинга нет ни тега <script> ни тега video